# Cálculo de horas para ponto PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, matemática

Estou criando uma tabela para o cálculo de horas trabalhadas de funcionários, mas não estou conseguindo fazer o cálculo pra saber se foi trabalhada a quantidade correta de horas no dia.

No banco de dados está dessa forma: 
[image: 1]

No site vai ser exibido dessa forma:
[image: 2]

Na última coluna, em "Horas Trabalhadas" preciso colocar o resultado do cálculo da Entrada 1 (Início do dia), Saída 1 (Almoço), Entrada 2 (Retorno do Almoço) e Saída 2 (fim do dia)

Usei esse select para pegar todos os dados da tabela:

```
SELECT p.id_ponto, p.tb_user_id_user, p.tb_ponto_mes_id_ponto_mes, p.dia_ponto, p.dt_entrada1, p.dt_saida1, p.dt_entrada2, p.dt_saida2, u.id_user, u.nm_user
FROM tb_ponto p
INNER JOIN tb_user u on u.id_user = p.tb_user_id_user
```

Estou exibindo os valores assim:

```
echo '<tr><td>' . $item["nm_user"] . '</td>' . 
'<td>' . $item["dia_ponto"] . '/' . $item["tb_ponto_mes_id_ponto_mes"] . '/2017' . '</td>' .  
'<td>' . $item["dt_entrada1"] . '</td>' . 
'<td>' . $item["dt_saida1"] . '</td>' . 
'<td>' . $item["dt_entrada2"] . '</td>' . 
'<td>' . $item["dt_saida2"] . '</td>' . 
'<td>8 Horas</td></tr>';
```

Como posso fazer pra calcular isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, o que você quer é o resultado em horas a partir dessas strings. É possível ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
// Faz o cálculo das horas
$total = (strtotime($item['dt_saida1']) - strtotime($item['dt_entrada1'])) + (strtotime($item['dt_saida2']) - strtotime($item['dt_entrada2']));

// Encontra as horas trabalhadas
$hours      = floor($total / 60 / 60);

// Encontra os minutos trabalhados
$minutes    = round(($total - ($hours * 60 * 60)) / 60);

// Formata a hora e minuto para ficar no formato de 2 números, exemplo 00
$hours = str_pad($hours, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$minutes = str_pad($minutes, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

// Exibe no formato "hora:minuto"
echo $hours.':'.$minutes;
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado! Agora, só tenho uma outra dúvida, a exibição está assim: 8:0, é possível fazer assim: 08:00 ou 8:00?

Comment: Tem sim, fiz uma alteração no código. Olhe ali.

Comment: Tudo perfeito, muito obrigado!

Comment: Por nada hehe. :)